# Encrypt / decrypt with public / private hex keypair using crypto in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography

I am very new to cryptography, so I am experimenting with encryption/decryption using the `crypto` module in node.js. I have the following, which works fine, but I would like to use shorter hex values for the public and private keys instead of PEM.

```
let text = "some text to encrypt"
crypt(text)
function crypt(text){
    const { generateKeyPairSync, publicEncrypt, privateDecrypt } = require('crypto');

    //generate a key pair RSA type encryption with a .pem format
    const { publicKey, privateKey } = generateKeyPairSync('rsa', {
    modulusLength: 512, // shortened from 4096
    publicKeyEncoding: {
        type: 'spki',
        format: 'pem'
    },
    privateKeyEncoding: {
        type: 'pkcs8',
        format: 'pem',
    }
    })

    // print out the generated keys
    console.log(`PublicKey: ${publicKey}`)
    console.log(`PrivateKey: ${privateKey}`)

    //message to be encrypted
    var toEncrypt = text
    var encryptBuffer = Buffer.from(toEncrypt)

    //encrypt using public key
    var encrypted = publicEncrypt(publicKey,encryptBuffer)

    //print out the text and cyphertext
    console.log("Text to be encrypted:")
    console.log(toEncrypt)
    console.log("cipherText:")
    console.log(encrypted.toString())
    //decrypt the cyphertext using the private key
    var decryptBuffer = Buffer.from(encrypted.toString("base64"), "base64")
    var decrypted = privateDecrypt(privateKey,decryptBuffer)

    //print out the decrypted text
    console.log("decrypted Text:")
    console.log(decrypted.toString())

    return encrypted.toString("base64")
}
```

I found [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/node-js-crypto-generatekeypair-method/) which shows how to generate the kind of key pair I want, but it doesn't show how to encrypt or decrypt using that key pair. I tried adapting it to my code above but ran into all kinds of problems.

```
// Node.js program to demonstrate the 
// crypto.generateKeyPair() method 

// Including generateKeyPair from crypto module 
const { generateKeyPair } = require('crypto'); 

// Calling generateKeyPair() method 
// with its parameters 
generateKeyPair('ec', { 
namedCurve: 'secp256k1', // Options 
publicKeyEncoding: { 
    type: 'spki', 
    format: 'der'
}, 
privateKeyEncoding: { 
    type: 'pkcs8', 
    format: 'der'
} 
}, 
(err, publicKey, privateKey) => { // Callback function 
    if(!err) 
    { 
        // Prints new asymmetric key 
        // pair after encoding 
        console.log("Public Key is: ", 
                publicKey.toString('hex')); 
        console.log(); 
        console.log("Private Key is: ", 
                privateKey.toString('hex')); 
    } 
    else
    { 
        // Prints error 
        console.log("Errr is: ", err); 
    } 
        
});
```

For my purposes, an example of how to encrypt/decrypt for this 2nd set of code would be very helpful

Comment: You have already noticed that we are talking about "two pairs of shoes"? The first example is working with a RSA key pair, the second one is using an Elliptic Curve (EC) key pair ?

Comment: Regarding your question: have a look to the NodeJs Crypto documentation: https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createprivatekey_key - in the second example you generate the key in **DER** encoding and a hex string output, you simply need a hex string to buffer converter and feed the buffer to the createPrivateKey function (as same for the public key to the createPublicKey counterpart)

Comment: @MichaelFehr Okay.. Yes, I am aware they are two different methods for encryption. What I'm reading seems to suggest that I have what I need already between the two sets of code? If so, I will keep working on it with the tip you provided.

Comment: EC cannot encrypt directly, but you might be able to use ECIES, which uses ECDH with a static key pair (from the receiver) and an ephemeral key pair (at the sender) to implement hybrid cryptography. There, now you've got some stuff to google at least, Wikipedia has a page about IES.